# Cut a sphereMovie texture into multiple halves in Unity and play a different video on each half

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, decoding

I have a big sphere Movie Texture on unity where I am playing or displaying my decoded video frames. Now, I want to display multiple decoded frames at same time on the sphereMovie multiple sections.

Can anyone please tell me how can I divide the sphereMovie into 4 halves (four subtextures), I can assign each of the subtexture to play one video at one time.

Can anyone please tell me how can I able to cut the 3D sphereMovie textures in these ways?

Comment: "With extreme difficulty."

Comment: @Draco18s, can u please elaborate a little bit how to achieve that. I right now have no clue regarding that. Any help will highly be appreciated.